Why did Shreemad Bhagavatam Mahapuran
Why did Shreemad Bhagavatam Mahapuran say in canto 1 chapter 3 that Ved Vyas appear before Shree Ram? And other Purna like padam and garud also said the same thing?

This question is similar to: Why does the Bhagavata Purana say Vyasa incarnated before Rama?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
